# Shipping costs per vendor (looking for extension)

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento2.4, shipping-methods, dropshipping

We are employing drop shipping for the product of our Magento 2 instance, but we need to have separate shipping costs for each vendor that sends the product to the customer on their own. So if

- Vendor A has zero shipping costs
- Vendor B has € 5,- shipping costs
- Vendor C has € 10,- shipping costs

and the cart consists of

- 2 Products from vendor A,
- 3 Products from vendor B,
- 10 Products from vendor C

then the total shipping costs should be € 15,- (ideally listed separately). In essence it should be handled as Amazon does it (separate shipping costs for separate products grouped by vendor).

There are a lot of extensions out there that implement additional shipping cost rules in Magento - however none of them seem to cover that exact use case. Some can implement additional shipping surcharges depending on product attributes (but they then also sum up, which is not desired), some can implement additional shipping costs per product.

May be in our extension research we missed some (or simply missed the right settings in the respective extensions). Does anyone know, which extension (regardless of paid or free and which price) can cover such a use case?